# How to do a VMEXIT in kvm on every branch instruction?

Tags: linux, virtualization

Debugging features like GDB work by setting the TF flag of eflags register which causes an exception after every execution of instruction by the processor. When we are running a virtual machine Ex in case of kvm to do the same thing you need to set a flag called the MONITOR TRAP FLAG (pg 15 of current intel software manual 3c), which will cause the virtual macine to EXIT (VMEXIT) after every instruction giving debugging abitily to the hypervisor.

I am facing a issue where I need to set BTF (branch Trap Flag)(PG 689 vOLUME 3a INTEL sotfware manual). In a normal scenario this cause DEBUG EXCEPTION on every branch instruction but since I want to this on a VM, I am not able to figure which bit to set in the VMCS. There seems to be no direct way doing this like in the case of single stepping. Can anyone let me know If there some way to do the same thing using other means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTF flag is not in the VMCS; it's in the IA32_DEBUGCTL MSR.
You need to set it explicitly by doing wrmsr before the VM entry.
For KVM you could add this in vmx_vcpu_run.

In order to cause a VM exit for all debug exceptions, set bit 1 of the exception bitmap in the VMCS. The information about the debug exception that caused the VM exit is saved in the exit qualification field of the VMCS. The hypervisor can then process the debug exception itself or inject it into the guest.